# Passing two arguments to skicit model.predict()

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I made this for an exercise on linear regression algorithm:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
model = LinearRegression()

X = housing[['lotsize',"bedrooms"]]
y = housing[['price']]

model.fit(X, y)
```

And i am stuck on the next part where i m supposed to call my results, i know how to do it with 1 argument for example: `model.predict([[400]])` if i was only using the `lotsize`

How do i write that `model.predict` if i am giving it two arguments ? (lotsize and bedrooms which takes values between 0 and 3)

I am sure that it's something simple but i am having a hard time finding the right syntax...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like:

```
model.predict([[400, 1]]) #[[x1, x2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You must define your model what to do when observing empty features like giving mean to that feature or median or 'nuknown' ,etc. Google something like this:

> Ways to handle missing values in machine learning

Comment: Thank you, i will check it out.